# Hitting Presigned URL to download object and get access denied exception

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, access-denied, aws-sdk-js, pre-signed-url

In our code base, we are aiming to render the S3 GetObject SignedURL for the client, so the client can download the object by clicking the url in the website .

Here is the v2 code:

```
return s3Client.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
           ...UDMSController.parseS3URI(s3URI),
           Expires: config.udms.s3.signedURLTTL,
         });
```

Here is the upgraded V3 code

```
const getObjectParams: GetObjectCommandInput = { Bucket: parsedS3URI.host, Key: parsedS3URI.pathname.substr(1) };
const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
return await getSignedUrl(s3Client, command, {expiresIn: config.udms.s3.signedURLTTL});
```

The IAM role we are assuming is the external account S3 permission role, here is the their S3 permission, basically, they did not change their permission

```
{
   "s3:Put*",
   "s3:List*",
   "s3:Get*",
}
```

And the client hit the URL we render on the website, they get `accessDenied` exception.

Here is the failed request

```
https://ring-data-requests-dev.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/gdpr/exports/user-46364072/10001357/datarequest.zip?

X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&

X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&

X-Amz-Credential=ASIA5JGQ37JDTMSI4DYI%2F20231204%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&

X-Amz-Date=20231204T180657Z&

X-Amz-Expires=600&

X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEPv%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIAc91WgOnR7Ry7tFwAN3bxAcwnZU3ehq2ENWm20MmevEAiEAhABAuMGiuVdcP6F7L%2BCqltrVh8%2FibtD2Z8uHa%2Ff2sR4qogIIYxADGgw5MTMxMTg1OTE1NTkiDGl7KMFE0%2BweJIPx4ir%2FAaO6C2bV7YLDAOR8EeYLwWA3jErDB9alj77gDoBNSbow6EMla3rLwXD2DbGN6k2tc6L8E2fGbbYenVMwGYt1Er%2Bf1pmXknqMgkhl7XpE3vq8HIIA7gTq%2BzKnfkLkILzJ2KcV%2BydA4%2Fzf7OphnHUgxCs30aAnG7cG1V3v2QVyWAd13%2Bx0evHww2GnZZeCcs9oAb4iZnmgg96kvfGOejGprshhQh83BB299T4336LOmpcByFz5fDxecmcOzMd%2Bmb4cqCuDDmMCsIhJ9nzve5hmZVv3hNuOonum6ROPHEzvAw17qMK7hhUL3Qn0vQjg6m6VIfbVAU1zXJg2AXROg6br7TDBqrirBjqdAQKuiFH5cVTfh2G1dLDtJkVQr5%2F2zCuBY20VQ3%2FTuYNtecpL%2FV%2BzDUIJiEcjgVboeMG%2F9%2BLbjwgrKBI7G0h0%2BqQ%2F4C0Ew9q4mPQmkcEUFahKMPLVU0w9sLJE07kfKfa8o6WlOoE4HM1WLm0SnEUswLy6F1M%2BKVqB%2FDP3J8xvIxO2nB0yhEkwTctP1%2BtBBSfG4ynAAvJgLC8e00dgzwc%3D&

X-Amz-Signature=08870a418d16e84832b20b44b1a9b7bc47dd0cc8193c4084831a99c7668a5800&

X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&

x-id=GetObject
```

The sample S3 path is:

```
s3://ring-data-requests-dev/gdpr/exports/user-82032267/10001355/datarequests.zip
```

We can get the URL and S3Path without error in our side, the issue is client keep getting accessDenied.

Does anyone know for this kind of upgrade, will the S3 role need extra permission? Or in our code base that we are missing any setup?

My assumption is the new SDK version let the request `X-Amz-Content-Sha256` be assigned as `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` and the bucket might reject reqeust with `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` content. Appreciate for any helps and hints here.

Thanks!

Expect the client won't face the accessDenied issue, Tried with grant the source s3 bucket with full S3 permission but still get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue after reviewing the code, there was two IAM roles I need to assume. I missed the second one. I use role A's credentials to call get Object, which lets S3 throw the ACE.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).